# Слайдер для сайта с текстом

Tags: html, css, slider

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо сверстать такой слайдер или что-то наподобие. Изображение должно увеличиваться при наведении и должен появляться соответствующий текст сверху.

Comment: А как Вы пытались это сделать? Вы код попытки добавьте, с этим помогать Вам будут гораздо охотнее

Comment: Можете взять за основу bxslider https://bxslider.com/, дописать скрипт который будет увеличивать изображение при наведении и показывать текст сверху.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!